# Dynamically change Log In name in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, login-name

I put `asp:LoginName` in my Master Page file ,

```
<asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />
```

The `asp:LoginName` show User Name by default ,
how can I show user's other data , such as email .
I want to write this process in `LoggingIn` Event .

```
void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
 .......
}
```

Comment: Actually what you are trying...?

Comment: I want to dynamically assign data to LoginName > asp:LoginName show User Name ( For Example >  John ) , but i want to show User's email ( For Example > John@yahoo.com ) .

Comment: from where you are getting `John` and how you are assigning. can u post code. Because you details are not enough and its not clear.

Comment: @RJK , I use asp.net membership provider .

Answer (score 1):

```
void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
LoginName _loginName = Master.FindControl("LoginName1") as LoginName;
_loginName.FormatString = "User's_Email" ;
}
```

Comment: It's better if you write this code in LoggedIn Event instead of LoggingIn .